# Best way to implement a to hit formula based on provided stats

Tags: mathematics, game-design, rpg, browser-based-games

There are a ton of these questions, some can get really mathy - which is fine, but I am looking for a simple way based on a few stats, I thought I came up with one, so I will share it in hopes that someone can tell me where I might be going wrong.

The goal is that the monster should, depending on how powerful you are, be able to have a chance to hit. Weaker monsters instant death to them, harder monsters possible instant death to you.

**I also realize these are hard questions to answer because it is game dependant. I hope I have provided enough info for you to give some guidance.**

Lets get the stats out the way:

- To Hit Stat (Character): base stat / modded stat (ie: 12/100)
- Accuracy / Dodge (Character): between 0.0001 - 1.0 (0.01% - 100% (can be higher))
- Enemy Dodge / Enemy Accuracy: Between 0.0001 - 0.85 (0.01% - 85%)
- To Hit (Monster): Dex / 10,000 - where 10k is 1k higher then max stats (9k) for monsters
- Monsters do have a max level (if that will help)

When a character levels they get 1 point into their base stat - which is then used in conjunction with all equipment and so on to increase the modded stat additively (base stat + base stat * bonuses = modded stat)

Characters can cap out (Modded stat) Higher then 10K which might pose issues for a to hit formula. How ever at that point I would assume your skills are 100% as max level is 1000 - thus you should always be hitting

The idea I had was ([based off another question asked](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136577/the-simplest-but-most-effective-and-intuitive-way-to-implement-accuracy-and-dodg)):

```
(stat / modded stat) + (((accuracy - dodge) / accuracy) * 100)
```

Some assumptions I made based on how I built the system:

- Accuracy at 100%+ means you always hit
- Dodge at 100%+ Means you always dodge.
- Enemies dodge and accuracy do not go above 85% (they can start at 0.01% for both)
- Monsters always use their dex (ie 12/max cap), monsters do not have modded stats

  - All Monster stats are the same, IE: if Dex is 9k all other stats, such as str, int, chr ... are also 9k

There are some issues with this formula though:

- If stat and stat mod are the same (no equipment or bonus for character only) I chose to use the stat (as opposed to stat / modded stat) so, if 11 === 11 - well, use 11. For the character (see below for example)
- Because a character might never train (I don't know why) Accuracy or Dodge their bonus might be 0.01% (there are equipment bonuses that can increase this to a max of 30% across all equipment with another 5% for boons (135% max) how ever in the following example we will assume you have nothing)

So:

```
   Level 1 (Character) = (11) + ((0.0001 - 0.0001) / 0.001) * 100) = 11 // Nothing equipped no bonuses

   vs.

   Rat (Enemy) = (8/10000) + ((0.0001 - 0.0001) / 0.001) * 100) = 0.0008
```

This doesn't seem right, so the player has a 11% to hit and the rat has a 0.0008% chance to hit?

Character : 100 - 11 = 82% chance to hit
Rate : 100 - 0.0008 = 99.9992% chance to hit?

This doesn't make sense to me. For context here's a high level monster with a character that has a 95% dodge chance:

```
 (9000/10000) + ((0.75 - 0.95) / 0.75) * 100) = -25.7666666667
```

That does not look right.

Comment: When both accuracy and dodge are 100%, what should happen in your system?

Comment: I don't understand why you would calculate your hit stat based on `base stat / modded stat`. What's the design intention behind that?

Comment: And what is the conceptual difference between "to hit" and "accuracy"? Why have two stats which apparently represent the same thing (likeliness to hit your target)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give you a few options to handle `accuracy` and `dodge`, pick the one that better suits you. *I have no idea about the other stats.*

---

### Accuracy is paramount

For our first option, if an attack has 100% `accuracy`, `dodge` does not matter. Even if `dodge` is 100%, when `accuracy` is 100%, `dodge` does not matter.

In fact, the probability of hitting are at least `accuracy`. That is, the formula will be `accuracy` plus some other term.

This is the formula:

```
probability = accuracy + (100% - accuracy) * (100% - dodge)
```

Of course, the second term is a function of `dodge`. I made it `100% - dodge` because less `dodge` should be easier to hit. Also, it has a factor of `100% - accuracy`. The idea is to scale down the effect of the second term as `accuracy` increases.

With this formula, the only case where it is impossible to hit is when `accuracy` is 0%, and `dodge` is 100%. Furthermore, you get perfect chance of hitting when either `accuracy` is 100% or `dodge` is 0%.

---

**Notes**:

- If you use `1/x` instead of `1-x` your distribution will be asymptotic (probabilities approach infinity, and of course you have division by 0). Don't do that.
- The formula might have problems when a variable goes over 100%. Because `1-x` would be negative. If `accuracy` is less or equal to 100%, clamp `dodge` to 100%. If `accuracy` is greater than 100%, you can either clamp both to 100%, or only clamp `dodge` to `100% - accuracy/(100% - accuracy)`, which allows values of `dodge` over 100% result in less probability than `accuracy`.

---

### Dodge is paramount

When `dodge` is 100%, there is no chance of hitting. Even if `accuracy` is 100%, when `dodge` is 100%, `accuracy` does not matter.

For this formula, `accuracy` means more chance of hitting, insofar `dodge` allows it. In fact, the probability of hitting will never be greater than `100% - dodge`. And we accomplish that by using it as a factor for `accuracy`.

This is the formula:

```
probability = accuracy * (100% - dodge)
```

Here the only way to have perfect chance of hitting is when `dodge` is 0% and `accuracy` is 100%. If either `dodge` is 100%, or `accuracy` is 0% it is impossible to hit.

---

**Note**: Here we also have a case of `1-x`. However, being a formula of a single term, your options are to clamp both variables to 100%, or clamp the result (which is how you would handle negatives).

---

### Generalization

So, you want something kind of in the middle?

This is the difference of the two formulas:

```
nuonce = accuracy * dodge + (100% - accuracy)(100% - dodge)
```

Now you can explore a continuum between the two formulas like this:

```
probability = accuracy * (100% - dodge) + nuonce * f
```

Where `f` goes from 0 to 1.

Regardless of `f`. When `accuracy` is 100% and `dodge` is 0%, it always hits. And when `accuracy` is 0% and `dodge` is 100%, it is impossible to hit.

When `f = 1` you get the first formula, and when `f = 0` you get the second. Furthermore, `f` is the probability when `accuracy` and `dodge` are both 0% or when they are both 100%.

---

There is an special case: When `f = 0.5`, the formula is a plane (for all other values, we have an hyperbolic paraboloid a.k.a. a saddle). For `f = 0.5` the formula simplifies to this:

```
probability = 50% * (accuracy - dodge + 100%)
```

As you can see, in this special case, you get 50% whenever `accuracy` and `dodge` are equal (not only when they are both 0% or both 100%, which is true for any value of `f`).

---

### Skewing

If you want to control the probability when both `dodge` and `accuracy` are 0% independently of the probability when both `dodge` and `accuracy` are 100%, there is a way. Notice that the formula I gave you for nuonce has two terms:

```
nuonce = accuracy * dodge + (100% - accuracy)(100% - dodge)
```

I could have expressed the difference multiple ways, but this terms has a meaning. It will be clearer here:

```
probability = accuracy * (100% - dodge)
    + p * accuracy * dodge
    + q * (100% - accuracy)(100% - dodge)
```

Now `p` is the probability when both `accuracy` and `dodge` are 100%. And `q` is the probability when both `accuracy` and `dodge` are 0%.

*All that is missing is for you to decide.*

Comment: This is very helpful, The only issue is it does not solve the issue of using stats. (ie: Stat mod and dex) its completely skill based, making your (character) "to_hit_stat"  and the monsters dex completely useless. But does give me a good starting point to understand which direction to go.

Comment: @KyleAdams I have no idea what stat mod, dex, and to_hit_stat should do or relate to each other. If you have some examples of inputs and output, perhaps I can figure out something. Accuracy and Dodge is the only part that made some sense to me, and even there, I still don't know what the probability of hitting should be when they are both 100%.

Comment: It seems like I am not the only one who can't make any sense of that. @KyleAdams If you answered the clarification requests I posted on the question, then you might get more relevant answers.

Comment: I was going the wrong way, this actually works for my use cases